# responsive design - which type of css does it use?

Tags: css, responsive-design

when i have this Code

HTML

```
<div id = 'bl'>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  #bl {
     font-size: 12px;
     Color: #ff0000;
     ......

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 799px) 
{
  #bl {
     border: 1px solid #ff0000;
   }
}
```

it's only an example.

which type of Code does it use when the Screen size is  between 0 and 799? both or only the one in media query without the other "bl" (font-size...)?

Comment: so the complete style from media query overwrite the other one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The styles get applied from a top down approach. So, the first style would be read and computed, then the media query styles would overwrite the styles above if the screen is within 0 and 799px.

Answer (score 0):

Both.

but if you had :-

```
#bl {
     font-size: 12px;
     Color: #ff0000;
     ...
     border: 2px solid red;
```

Then the `border` in media query would then override.